# Delete from 2 tables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in DB

`food`

```
id  name  ... food_menu
```

and `food_drinks`

```
food_id    drinks_id
```

food_menu is equal to drinks_id. On the page I have button next to some food and when I click it is delete that food from table `food`. The problem is can I delete in the same time related drinks_id from `food_drinks` in same query?

This is what I use now to delete the food.

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM food WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

else
{
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: Possibly enforce referential integrity and allow cascade delete. like: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/.  You could also call a procedure instead and have the procedure do both...

Comment: @sjagr No, that is not correct

Comment: MySQL does support `JOIN` deletes. But you say _food_menu is equal to drinks_id_. That seems wrong - do you mean to say that `food_drinks.food_id` refers to `food.id`?

Comment: Exactly `food_menu is equal on drinks_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete from multiple tables at once like this

```
DELETE f, fd
FROM food f
LEFT JOIN food_drinks fd on fd.drinks_id = f.food_menu
WHERE f.id = ?
```